# Поиск подстроки в string

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, struct

Имеется часть кода:

```
struct orders {
    string product;
    string mark;
    string surname;
    string name;
    string secondName;
    string phoneNumber;
    int cost;
    int dayOfRecept;
    int monthOfRecept;
    int yearOfRecept;
    int dayOfIssue;
    int monthOfIssue;
    int yearOfIssue;
    bool status;
};
void fullfillOrdersVector(vector<orders> &Ord) {
    orders Order;
    ifstream file("order.txt");
    while (file >> Order.product >> Order.mark >> Order.surname >> Order.name >> Order.secondName >> Order.phoneNumber >> Order.cost >> Order.dayOfRecept >> Order.monthOfRecept >>
        Order.yearOfRecept >> Order.dayOfIssue >> Order.monthOfIssue >> Order.yearOfIssue >> Order.status) {
        Ord.push_back(Order);
    }
    file.close();
}
void searchBySurname() {
    vector <orders> Ord;
    fullfillOrdersVector(Ord);
    cout << "Enter the surname/part of it" << endl;
    string inputString;
    cin >> inputString;
    int counter = 0;
    cout << "Product Mark Owner Phone number Cost Recept Issue Status" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < Ord.size(); i++) {
        if ((Ord[i].surname).find(inputString)) {
            cout << i << " " << Ord[i].product << " " << Ord[i].mark << " " << Ord[i].surname << " " << Ord[i].name << " " << Ord[i].secondName << " " << Ord[i].phoneNumber << " " <<
                Ord[i].cost << " " << Ord[i].dayOfRecept << " " << Ord[i].monthOfRecept << " " << Ord[i].yearOfRecept << " " << Ord[i].dayOfIssue << " " << Ord[i].monthOfIssue
                << " " << Ord[i].yearOfIssue << " " << Ord[i].status << endl;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        cout << "There're no such surnames in list" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Users found: " << counter << endl;
    }
}
```

Задача - считывание данных из файла в вектор структур, поиск данных с нужной фамилией/частью фамилии, и вывод на экран. Однако при выводе на экран получаю абсолютно обратный результат (т.е показываются все, кроме нужной). Подозреваю, что ошибка в строке с `(Ord[i].surname).find(inputString)`
Но не понимаю, что не так

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно подозреваете: 
`Ord[i].surname).find(inputString)`  всегда будет true, поскольку  `std::string::find()` 
при неудачи возвращает `string::npos`,  что из себя представляет большая цифра, 
(не ноль).
Поэтому проверка должна выглядеть так:

```
if ((Ord[i].surname).find(inputString) != string::npos) {...
```